# Spring Boot : Unable to set logging level via application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I am trying to set the logging level in the console to 'debug' in my Spring boot application by adding logging.level as debug in application.properties file but I am still seeing info level logging in the console:

[image]

I tried to set the logging level by adding the following statement in application.properties file:

logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG

Wanted to set the console logging level to debug. Could someone please help me on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, your syntax is correct. If it doesn't work then check if application.properties file is on the classpath. For example src/main/resources if you are using IDE. And you need to restart your application after any change of properties (of course).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add an additional node to the package path.

For reference, see the [Log Levels section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels) of the Spring docs, which shows an example of: *logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG*